# How do I set the command key as Super on osX?

Tags: osx, modifier-key

I am running the graphical version of Emacs 26.1 on osX, and I have

```
(when (eq system-type 'darwin)
  (setq ns-command-modifier 'super))
```

in my init.el. However, when I do e.g. `s-t`, it brings up the font selection menu instead of doing what I bound `s-t` to. [image]

This is the original behavior without the ns-command-modifier, so it seems like super is not being set. What do I need to do to set command key to Super?

Comment: In the world of Emacs as it relates to keyboard keys, we use the *lowercase* letter `s` to signify the super/command ⌘ key.  The *uppercase* letter `S` signifies the shift key.

Comment: Depending upon the version of OSX/MacOS, it may be helpful to check to see what system-wide keyboard shortcuts are assigned that potentially *trump* Emacs keyboard shortcuts.  E.g., click on the apple in the upper left-hand corner of the menubar, select System Preferences, select Keyboard, select the Shortcuts tab, then look at each individual category and all keyboard shortcut assignments within each category.

Comment: @lawlist I don't believe OSX is intercepting the keypress and doing something else - simply because command - t is used in other applications (e.g. to create a new tab in a web browser or terminal)

Comment: When we type `C-h k s-t` on OSX with a graphical Emacs 27, we get a `*Help*` buffer that states in relevant part:  "`s-t` runs the command `ns-popup-font-panel` (found in `global-map`), which is an interactive built-in function in `C source code`."

Comment: The keyboard shortcut `s-t` is defined in `ns-win.el` with the following Lisp code:  `(define-key global-map [?\s-t] 'ns-popup-font-panel)`  Copying that same format over to your `.emacs` / `init.el` file, you can reassign the keyboard shortcut to something else ...  E.g., `(define-key global-map [?\s-t] 'butterfly)` to assign the keyboard shortcut to the function `butterfly`.

Comment: ok, it seems like everything was working as expected earlier without having to do setq ns-command-modifer - my issue was binding "S-t" instead of "s-t". Thank you for your help